# Change postgres schema in Enterprise Architect in Server Based Repositories

Tags: repository, enterprise-architect, svn-repository

We have a Server Based Repositories with postgres DBMS for Enterprise Architect.

Enterprise Architect connect to postgress database just to public schema.
so I run "PostgreSQL_EASchema.sql" in public schema.

I want to change the schema for Enterprise Architect.
for Example I create new schema and run PostgreSQL_EASchema.sql in that schema.but EA cant connect to that schema and cant Find tables!
I cant config EA or its ODBC driver to use another schema.
i there any way to change default schema for EA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supplier-supported way to modify the schema for an EA repository.

Of course, you can modify it yourself using the appropriate DB admin tool, but there is no guarantee that EA will work afterwards.

Comment: you mean that I should create new database for every project in EA? I want to create new schemas for every new project.

Comment: Each project has its own database, and the schema is always the same. Unless you make your own changes to it, in which case EA may or may not work. Modifying the schema is certainly not recommended practice.